# Distance between two points on circle in specific direction

Tags: objective-c, math, distance, geometry

I have two points on my circle, (x1y1) and (x2y2). How do I calculate distance between them in counter and clock wise direction.
Currently, I am using following formula to calculate the distance between 2 points on circle.
Please suggest.

```
- (CGFloat)calculateDistanceBetween:(CGPoint)point1 point2:(CGPoint)point2
{
    CGFloat dx = point2.x - point1.x;
    CGFloat dy = point2.y - point1.y;
    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy );
}
```

Comment: Do you mean distance along the arc?  Your function doesn't look like it does anything like that.  What you have is just the linear distance between two points - no circle involved.  Clockwise/counterclockwise makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

This is a maths question really. You're looking for arc length (which equals angle in radians multiplied by radius)

Your function as it stands can't calculate an arc length, because it doesn't know where the circle is (it takes 3 points to define a circle).

```
- (CGFloat)calculateShortestArcDistanceBetween:(CGPoint)point1 point2:(CGPoint)point2 center:(CGPoint)center
{
    CGFloat dx1 = point1.x - center.x;
    CGFloat dy1 = point1.y - center.y;
    CGFloat dx2 = point2.x - center.x;
    CGFloat dy2 = point2.y - center.y;
    CGFloat angle1 = atan2f( dy1, dx1 );
    CGFloat angle2 = atan2f( dy2, dx2 );
    CGFloat angle = angle1 - angle2;
    if(      angle >  M_PI ) angle -= M_PI * 2;
    else if( angle < -M_PI ) angle += M_PI * 2;
    return fabs( angle ) * sqrtf( dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1 );
}

- (CGFloat)calculateDirectedArcDistanceBetween:(CGPoint)point1 point2:(CGPoint)point2 center:(CGPoint)center
{
    CGFloat dx1 = point1.x - center.x;
    CGFloat dy1 = point1.y - center.y;
    CGFloat dx2 = point2.x - center.x;
    CGFloat dy2 = point2.y - center.y;
    CGFloat angle1 = atan2f( dy1, dx1 );
    CGFloat angle2 = atan2f( dy2, dx2 );
    CGFloat angle = angle1 - angle2;
    if( angle < 0 ) angle += M_PI * 2;
    return angle * sqrtf( dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1 );
}
```

Most of the tricky bit is making sure the ranges are correct (`atan2` gives values from -pi to +pi, so after getting the difference between two angles we must re-normalise them)

Comment: Small remark: `hypotf` is a convenient function to compute the length of a vector.

Comment: @MartinR didn't know about that. Is it portable? A quick internet search didn't tell me.

Comment: My two points on circle are {180.109, 155.487} and {79.2966, 18.2268} I get length of an arc 221.778336 -221.778336 in both direction. which is not right! am I missing anything?

Comment: Modified function as below.   <code>
- (CGFloat)calculateDistanceBetween:(CGPoint)point1 point2:(CGPoint)point2 center:(CGPoint)center
{
    CGFloat dx1 = point1.x - center.x;
    CGFloat dy1 = point1.y - center.y;
    CGFloat dx2 = point2.x - center.x;
    CGFloat dy2 = point2.y - center.y;
    CGFloat angle1 = atan2f( dy1, dx1 );
    CGFloat angle2 = atan2f( dy2, dx2 );
    CGFloat angle = angle1 - angle2;
   
    return  angle * sqrtf( dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1 );
}<code>

Comment: You haven't said where your center point is. Also see my updated answer, which has the `if( angle < 0 )...` line (needed for directed angles)

Comment: numbers are not consistent. My center is at  {105, 105}. I get different numbers for same direction for same points. any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @supri not without seeing more code. The function I posted will work for any points as long as they really do form a circle (I.e. point1 and point2 are equidistant from center)

Comment: Also since this function is completely deterministic, there's no way you can get a different answer for the same input; something must be happening in the input or output code.